Automated Remote db syncing to localhost db?
i am looking for the best practice to sync my hosted db with my local db, to serve as backup and emergency db!
I need advice on the best solution that will consider speed and efficiency, without going through all the data and to minimiseload by targeting only the updates
i have mysql db hosted on hostgator

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html

Is it possible to configure your local host as a Replica to the hosted Primary?


I am looking for the best practice to sync my hosted db with my local db, to serve as backup and emergency db!

Best Practice is not to do this!
You must have database Backups.
Find out how hostgator can provide them and then verify that what they provide meets your needs.
I'm assuming that "sync"ing here means taking an "off-line" copy of the database, rather than any real-time data Replication.  The latter would be driven from the hosting Server and it almost certainly wouldn't be able to access your local database anyway.  Also, as soon as you shut down your local computer, that replication would fail.
For that matter, your hosted Application almost certainly wouldn't be able to access your local database either, so using it as an "emergency database" is also doomed to failure.
If you are thinking of copying the database, then use Database tools to do so - do not think of your database as a bunch of files.  Most of what your DBMS does happens in the memory of a running [server] process.  Just grabbing the files while that process is running will get you incomplete and inconsistent files that you won't be able to restore (without losing a lot, possibly all, of your data).
